# Como recuperar os dados tragos na consulta da api no NODEJS

Tags: json, node.js, api, response

Bom dia Galera.

Estou consumindo uma api externa e estou recebendo os dados da seguinte forma:

```
{
"place_id": "151508663",
"licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
"osm_type": "way",
"osm_id": "348425570",
"lat": "-22.8799486",
"lon": "-43.1023092803839",
"display_name": "Colégio Nossa Sra das Mercês, Travessa Francisca Ribeiro, São Lourenço, Niterói, Microrregião Rio de Janeiro, Região Metropolitana do Rio de Janeiro, RJ, Região Sudeste, 24130-005, Brasil",
"address": {
    "school": "Colégio Nossa Sra das Mercês",
    "road": "Travessa Francisca Ribeiro",
    "suburb": "São Lourenço",
    "city": "Niterói",
    "county": "Microrregião Rio de Janeiro",
    "state_district": "Região Metropolitana do Rio de Janeiro",
    "state": "RJ",
    "postcode": "24130-005",
    "country": "Brasil",
    "country_code": "br"
},
"boundingbox": [
    "-22.8806171",
    "-22.8792948",
    "-43.1025817",
    "-43.1019949"
]
```

}

como posso acessar cada item desse no node, já tentei assim:

```
var id = [];
this.id = res.place_id;
```

Mais me trás undefined

podem me ajudar?

Comment: Carlos, você pode passar como está sendo efetuada a sua requisição?

Comment: Boa Tarde meu amigo, estou fazendo conforme o exemplo: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/10/consume-remote-api-data-nodejs-application/

Comment: Carlos, eu penso que o problema pode ser o fato de ser uma requisição assíncrona e com isso a sua atribuição estar sendo efetuada anterior ao retorno da API. Neste caso eu sugeriria a você utilizar o async/await (https://medium.com/@oieduardorabelo/padr%C3%B5es-de-design-com-async-await-em-node-js-fccfbe24572e) para buscar os dados ou então utilizar o axios (https://github.com/axios/axios) pois ele trabalha com promise e sua requisição não ficaria "para trás"

Comment: Vou tentar meu amigo obrigado, mais eu trago os dados sé não estou conseguindo acessa-los no array

Comment: beleza! Qualquer coisa dá um toque hehe.